# Is it possible to add a status check that checks if a service has started on an EC2 instance via Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am wondering if it's possible to add a status check on an EC2 instance via Terraform that checks if a given service has started.

I would like to check if the Docker service is started and if a container has been started from an image. Basically, I don't want to rush and log in when trying to debug issues, before the Docker container has started, because that takes a minute or two after the EC2 instance has started and I would like to make it a bit more intelligent.

My Terraform scripts provision the EC2 instance and already have things like the `user_data`, security groups, networking and other resources configured.

I have the following code:

```
module "runners_linux" {
  source                = "terraform-aws-modules/autoscaling/aws"
  version               = "~> 6.0"
  name                  = var.name_linux
  image_id              = data.aws_ami.ami_linux.id
  instance_type         = var.instance_type_linux
  security_groups       = [data.aws_security_group.default.id]
  key_name              = aws_key_pair.ssh_access_key.key_name

  # recreate_asg_when_lc_changes = true
  # above option does not exist, you will need to terminate running instances to take effect
  block_device_mappings = [
    {
      # Root volume
      device_name = "/dev/xvda"
      no_device   = 0
      ebs         = {
        delete_on_termination = true
        encrypted             = true
        volume_size           = 10
        volume_type           = "gp3"
      }
    }
  ]

  vpc_zone_identifier = [
    data.aws_subnet.infrashared.id
  ]

  health_check_type         = "EC2"
  desired_capacity          = 1
  min_size                  = 1
  max_size                  = 3
  wait_for_capacity_timeout = 0
  service_linked_role_arn   = aws_iam_service_linked_role.autoscaling.arn
  iam_instance_profile_arn  = aws_iam_instance_profile.ghr.arn
  user_data                 = base64encode(data.template_file.user_data_linux.rendered)
  tags                      = local.tags_linux

  scaling_policies = {
    avg-cpu-policy-greater-than-50 = {
      disable_scale_in              = true
      policy_type                   = "TargetTrackingScaling"
      estimated_instance_warmup     = 900
      target_tracking_configuration = {
        predefined_metric_specification = {
          predefined_metric_type = "ASGAverageCPUUtilization"
        }
        target_value = 50.0
      }
    }
  }

  # This does not work
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "systemctl is-active docker"
  }

  # This does not work
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "docker ps -f ancestor=ID-GOES-HERE.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/my-stuff:1.0.0"
  }
  
}
```

I've also read that `local-exec` is typically not really recommended. Is this the right way to go and how can I use it here?

Comment: Yes, through `local-exec`. Have you tried anything? Any specific issue/problem?

Comment: You can find docs for local-exec on TF website.

Comment: Can you describe in more detail the behavior you're looking for? What exactly do you mean by "status check". What is the larger goal?

Comment: Ok, so you want to check if a specific container is running. But I am still confused about the context. Do you want to do this as part of your terraform provisioning (e.g., make sure the container is running before terraform provisions another resource) -- or are you wanting to use terraform to provision a [EC2 status check](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-system-instance-status-check.html) to mark the instance as unhealthy if the container stops running for any reason?

Comment: I've updated my question's description. I was looking for a solution that would add a status check that would show if green, if the Docker service has started and the container is running, but what you mentioned as a health check if the Docker container stops is also a great idea to illustrate, if you know how.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement custom health checks for EC2 instances without using an ELB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43975456/how-to-implement-custom-health-checks-for-ec2-instances-without-using-an-elb)